# Add new package to angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

This question may be a duplicate, but I have not found an exact answer.

Let me explain to you. I am new to Angularjs. I have scaffolded a new project in angular using [angm](https://github.com/newaeonweb/generator-angm). This is done and is working find. But now I would like to add [faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker/tutorial) to my project to create test data for my application.

Usually in node applications, I go to `app.js` add `var faker = require('faker')`, then I use `npm install faker` and in my file I can use the variable `faker`.

But in the case of angular I don't know how to do it. Can someone please explain how to add new package to an Angularjs app ?

Comment: Do you mean "use faker on a browser"? If so, [simply load faker on your HTML and use the global var `faker`](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/#browser) Anyway, you can use the same node syntax (`var faker = require('faker')`) on your browser if you use `webpack` or something similar.

Comment: I would like to use it in homeServices.js file I have installed it with bower but there is and error. (`angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ang-modular due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module faker due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'faker' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`)
This is my angular file:
`▾ modules/
    ▾ home/
        dashboard.html
         homeService.js
`

Comment: I don't know what it is `homeServices.js`. I need more info, could you provide a codepen or similar? The error above simply says that `faker` is not an angular module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that as devDependencies in package.json. That's how a package is added in Angular applciation.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "assert": "~1.1.1",
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "faker": "*",
    "fs-extra": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "mocha": "*",
    "temp": "~0.8.0",
    "yeoman-assert": "^2.1.1",
    "yeoman-test": "^1.1.0"
  }
```